# School Project, set up OpenGL on VS 2019 Community

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, visual-studio-2019, glfw

I am trying to set up OpenGL on my PC for a project. The project gave me sample code to run and a folder to add include directories and libs to my sample code solution in VS 2019 community. The directions were awful and wanted me to upload the include and lib directories to VC++. This did not work even remotely, none of the glfw or glew headers were recognized. I found other directions online to upload the include folders under C/C++>General>Additional Include Directories and the libs under Link>General>Additional Lib Directories. Then I added glfw3.lib;glu32.lib;glew32.lib;opengl32.lib to my Link>Input>Additional Dependencies. This allowed my program to compile. But now I get the following errors plus 90 more like it:

````
Warning LNK4098 defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library OpenGLSample    C:\OpenGL_Projects\OpenGLSample\OpenGLSample\LINK   1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__TranslateMessage@4 referenced in function __glfwPlatformInit  OpenGLSample    C:\OpenGL_Projects\OpenGLSample\OpenGLSample\glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj)  1```
````

Comment: Whatever other information you need I can provide, I am just not sure what will even help.

Comment: You need to link to user32.lib

Comment: Less errors now only 18. next error is ```Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__CreateDCW@16 referenced in function __glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp OpenGLSample C:\Users\doubl\Desktop\OpenGL_Projects\OpenGLSample\OpenGLSample\glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj)```

Comment: CreateDCW is in GDI32.lib, so you probably want to link that.

Comment: Thank you guys, I figured out how to look up the libs that i was missing. Thank you for all of your help.